# How to change elementary OS branding?

Tags: release-loki

i have a assignment from my school for a remastering project.
so i need to change all elementary os branding.

how can i change "elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki" text on **System Setting -> About**

i have searched on google but still no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the source code of the [About plug](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-about):

- https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-about/blob/master/src/Plug.vala#L75-L100
- https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-about/blob/master/src/Plug.vala#L146-L151

Looks like it's retrieved from the "PRETTY_NAME" variable from the `/etc/os-release` file.

Does that help you?